# Check a value in an array inside a object json in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have an json object containing an array and others properties.

I need to check the first value of the array for each line of my table.

Here is an example of the json

```
{"objectID2":342,"objectID1":46,"objectType":["Demand","Entity"]}
```

So I need for example to get all lines with ObjectType[0] = 'Demand' and objectId1 = 46.

This the the table colums

```
id |  relationName | content
```

Content column contains the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just query them? like:

```
t=# with table_name(id, rn, content) as (values(1,null,'{"objectID2":342,"objectID1":46,"objectType":["Demand","Entity"]}'::json))
select * From table_name
where content->'objectType'->>0 = 'Demand' and content->>'objectID1' = '46';
 id | rn |                              content
----+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |    | {"objectID2":342,"objectID1":46,"objectType":["Demand","Entity"]}
(1 row)
```